# Confusing about numpy/pandas nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
x = """a,b
,bb
2,
,,"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x))
print(df)
     a    b
0  NaN   bb
1  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN

print([[type(__) for __ in df[_]] for _ in df ])
[[float, float, float], [str, float, float]]

print([set(df[_]) for _ in df])
[{nan, nan, 2.0}, {nan, 'bb'}]
```

As you can see, all `nan`s are float, but `set(df.b)` gives unique values. while it appears that the two `nan` in column `a` are different. Why?

Besides, what's the reason for the following differences

```py
[type(_) for _ in df.a]
Out[370]: [float, float, float]

[type(df.a[i]) for i in range(len(df.a))]
Out[371]: [numpy.float64, numpy.float64, numpy.float64]
```

which are different (though all of float type, but different classes)

```py
[type(_) for _ in df.b]
Out[374]: [str, float, float]

[type(df.b[i]) for i in range(len(df.b))]
Out[373]: [str, float, float]
```

which are the same

Comment: It looks like it's a numpy thing, not just Pandas. When the datatype is `object`, then the `nan` check is different than when the datatype is `float`.

Comment: Pandas display doesn't distinguish string, python `nan` and `np.nan` values.   In the column with the string, the `dtype` is object, and `nan` are python floats.  The other column is a `np.float` dtype array.

Comment: @hpaulj is there a builtin `nan` for python? input `nan` raises `NameError: name 'nan' is not defined`

Comment: `float('nan')` produces this object; it doesn't normally have its own python name.  `np.nan` creates the same thing.  But keep in mind that `nan` is not equal to anything, not even itself.  So testing for it is tricky.  `np.isnan` helps.   `pandas` has more powerful/general tools for testing and replacing `nan` (and similar values).